# What would be the resultant Binary search tree after deletion of root node in given BST?

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

Given BST is as below

```
                  {10}

      {5}                       {30}

 {2}        {7}          {25}        {40}

                      {20}                {50}

                             {22}
```

I came across this  BST while practicing BST deletion concept.here, how can i delete the root node or 10 from above BST such that after deletion resultant tree maintains BST properties.?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on your balancing algorithm, but one possible representation is:

```
                  {30}

      {5}                       {25}

 {2}        {7}           {20}        {40}

                              {22}        {50}
```

Another is

```
                  {30}

      {5}                       {25}

 {2}        {7}           {22}        {40}

                      {20}                {50}
```

or

```
                  {30}

      {5}                       {40}

 {2}        {7}           {22}        {50}

                      {20}    {25}
```

Comment: Thanks paul. can you help me out to understand how 30 became root node. is it possible to generate same representation  without doing any balancing

Comment: Something has to be the root node, so you have to promote one of the subordinate nodes to the root position.  I arbitrarily chose 30 -- could have just as easily been 5.  You will always have to reshuffle (if not balance) the tree when you remove a node (from that node downward).  Read up on AVL trees for more detail. https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/AVLtree.html

Comment: That is actually the first representation.

Comment: here i don't want to balancing the BST. i just want to follow the deletion rules which says that  if node has both left and right subtree then  first find the in-order successor(20 in this case) of 10  and swap  the content of root and  in-order successor.in this case ,  my root node become 20  and then delete 10 by  adjusting parent pointer of 10 to its in-order successor. but in this case , parent of 10 would be 25 and in-order successor of 25  would be 30 then how can i connect 25 node to 30.  i just want to know is it possible to deletion 10 without any rotation?